# How to generate/edit .ubin file generated by OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt

I have precompiled OpenWrt .ubin file. My router producer has given me that file. I want to change router web page. I tried compiling OpenWrt but it is generating .bin and OpenWrt doesnt have my router profile. So I need to use same given .ubin.